# Problem when using datetime data to draw graphic

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, matplotlib, graphics

I want to draw a graphic with using datas in datetime format as xaxis, but the process lasts very, very, extremly long, over 30 mins there is still no graphic. But once I apply datas in another column, the graphic will occur very soon. All the datas' formats are 'list'.
I'm confused about that, since they are all in the same format, why I can't draw the graphic out using the datetime formate as xaxis??
here is my code, I cherish all your time and help!

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import csv

names = []
x = []
y = []
names=[]
with open('all.csv','r') as csvfile: #this csv file contains over 16000 datas
    plots= csv.reader(csvfile,delimiter=',')
    for row in plots:
        x.append(row[1]) #row1 is the datetime format data
        y.append(row[2])
    print(x,y)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Lines of my csv file look something like:

```
2016/05/02 10:47:45,14.1,20.1,N.C.,170.7,518.3,-1259,-12.61,375.8,44.92,13.76,92.74,132.6,38.86,165.3,170.9,311.5,252.3,501.2,447.2,378.4,35.48,7.868,181.2,
```

I want the first column as xaxis and the following colums as yaxis...

and the y axis doesn't change, no matter how I change the y axis limit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('all.csv')
x = df.iloc[:,1]
y = df.iloc[:,3]
x = pd.to_datetime(x)
plt.figure(num=3, figsize=(15, 5))
plt.plot(x,y)
my_y_ticks = np.arange(0, 40, 10)
plt.xticks(rotation = 90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: You need to [edit] your question and add a sample of the input csv file's contents.

Comment: ok. I am gonna do it right now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I havent understood exactly what you mean with `all the datas' format are list`, but I think you could use something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('all.csv')
x = df.iloc[:,0]
y = df.iloc[:,1]
x = pd.to_datetime(x)
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Maybe showing some rows can be useful

### EDIT:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
df = pd.read_csv('all.csv')
x = df.iloc[:,0] 
y = df.iloc[:,1]

x = pd.to_datetime(x, format="%Y/%m/%d %H/%M/%S") #if the format is different, change here
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y)
xfmt = mdates.DateFormatter("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(xfmt)
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works!!!But the xaxis only shows year and month, actually my datetime format in csv file is like: 'year/month/day hour/min/sec', but the graphic shows!

Comment: You are welcome! How do you want the xaxis to be showed?

Comment: :))) Actually I want a more specific time scale for xaxis, for example: 2016/05/02 10:47:45, but now in the graphic it's : 2016-05.

Comment: @It'sNele I've updated the answer. If the solution works, please consider to accept the answer :)

Comment: Of course, but there are still some problems when I want to change the  yaxis scale, do you probably know how to change the y scale? whatever how I set the limit of yaxis, the graphic does't change...I added the new codes in the question..

Comment: @It'sNele use `ax.set_ylim(min_val, max_val)`